# How to create an activity log in sql?

Tags: java, sql

I'm using sql tables for backend purposes.  Now I need to create Activity log for one particular table.
Is it possible? If yes, please give me the way to do? I'm new to sql.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a another replica of your table, and write a trigger on insert, update and delete.

http://www.sql.org/sql-database/postgresql/manual/sql-createtrigger.html

Answer (score 1):

[Trigger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger) is what you need here. They are good choice for maintaining log on specific table.

A trigger can be specified to **fire automatically** either before the operation (INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE is attempted) or AFTER the operation has been attempted (e.g., after constraints are checked and the INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE has completed).